# How can I enable zoom in & zoom out in android web app?

Tags: java, android, xml

I created an android web app, and I want to apply zoom in & zoom out, but I don't know how!! Please help me.

I need java and xml examples, if anyone can provide me. I searched but I didn't find a helpful solution.

Thank you, 
Haya

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must check out your meta tags about user zoom, scaling

If you have any code like this on your web app you can't scale it

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

please use code below

to disable zoom:

```
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

to disable zoom controls:

```
 webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

and to disable LongClick :) :

```
webView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return true;
        }
    });

webView.setLongClickable(false);
```